# What is the difference between sealed class vs sealed interface in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

With Kotlin `1.5` was introduce the `sealed interface`. Even that I know the difference between classes and interfaces, I'm not clear what are the best practices and beneficies of using `sealed interface` over `sealed class`

Should I always use `interface` now even when is a simple case? Or will be a case by case?

Thanks

Obs: Didn't found similar questions, only about `sealed classes`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A major reason to choose to use a sealed class instead of interface would be if there is common property/function that you don't want to be `public`. All members of an interface are always public.

The restriction that members must be `public` can be worked around on an interface using extension functions/properties, but only if it doesn't involve storing state non-publicly.

Otherwise, sealed interfaces are more flexible because they allow a subtype to be a subclass of something else, an enum class, or a subtype of multiple sealed interface/class hierarchies.

Comment: This answer is great, but if you want to read more about sealed interfaces with some code I suggest this article --> https://jorgecastillo.dev/sealed-interfaces-kotlin

Comment: No, answer is not great. Sorry, what means all members of an interface are always public and open? You can mark them as private.

Comment: @Sever it is forbidden by the compiler to mark an interface function or property as `private`, `internal`, or `protected`, and they cannot be marked `final` at the declaration site. I realize the part about being open is misleading, so I'll remove that.

Comment: Thanks @JoãoDias for the references. the sealed interface by jorgecastillo is explains a lot!

Answer (score 28):

I would also add that `sealed interface` can be chosen instead of a `class`  to mark an object with additional characteristics and use it in the `when` statement. For example let's say we have some number of classes that inherited from a `sealed class Device`:

```
sealed class DeviceItem(val name: String) {
    object Camera : DeviceItem("Camera")
    object Lamp : DeviceItem("Lamp")
    // ... etc, more devices
}
```

And we need to use an instance of `DeviceItem` in `when` statement, but we don't want to handle all the items, only specific items:

```
fun onDeviceItemClicked(item: DeviceItem) {
    when (item) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

In this case we should either add all device items to the `when` statement with an empty body for devices that we don't want to handle, and the code becomes cumbersome, or use `else` statement to handle those device items with the empty body. But if we use `else` we will not be notified of the error, when a new device item is added and requires some handling, which can lead to bugs. Starting from `Kotlin 1.7` it will be a compilation error if `when` operator is not **exhaustive**. So basically to handle such cases we can provide a `sealed interface` and handle only items, which implement it:

```
sealed interface ClickableItem

sealed class DeviceItem(val name: String) {
    object Camera : DeviceItem("Camera"), ClickableItem
    object Lamp : DeviceItem("Lamp")
    // ... etc, more devices
}

fun onDeviceItemClicked(item: ClickableItem) {
    when (item) {
        Camera -> { /* do something */ }
    }
}
```

In this case when a new device item, which implements `ClickableItem` interface, is added there will be a compilation error, saying that `when` statement should be **exhaustive** and we must handle it.

Comment: Check the sealed class, replace Device with DeviceItem