# Proper way of using sealed interface in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-sealed

I am totally new to `sealed Interface` in Kotlin. I am trying to state management through `sealed` in Android Kotlin. My main goal is `when` I use the object of `sealed` I don't want to inherit all children. I am not sure if `sealed interface` is the right choice for me. All my code may be wrong, please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

```kotlin
    sealed interface ConnectionUIState
    
    sealed class BluetoothConnectionUIState {
        object Initial : BluetoothConnectionUIState()
        data class ScanningDevice(val storedDevice: SnapshotStateList<BluetoothDevice>? = null) : ConnectionUIState
    }
```

I initialise the variable like this:

```kotlin
    var uiState by mutableStateOf<BluetoothConnectionUIState>(BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial)
            private set
```

Now I am passing the `uiState` variable in the function and using `when` statement:

```kotlin
    when (uiState) {
            BluetoothConnectionUIState.ScanningDevice -> {
                xuz()
            }
        }
```

why `when` statement is giving error:

```
    'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'Initial' branch or 'else' branch instead
```

Also this line is also giving me error: `BluetoothConnectionUIState.ScanningDevice` in `when` statement.

**Error**

```
    Classifier 'ScanningDevice' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

If I am doing wrong here. Can you please elaborate of 2 point of this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573083/11560810). Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I did some changes:

```kotlin
    sealed interface ConnectionUIState
    
    sealed class BluetoothConnectionUIState {
        object Initial : ConnectionUIState
        data class ScanningDevice(val storedDevice: SnapshotStateList<BluetoothDevice>? = null) : BluetoothConnectionUIState()
    }
```

I did success on `when` statement that it's not complaining about `Initial`:

```kotlin
    when (uiState) {
            is BluetoothConnectionUIState.ScanningDevice -> {
                BluetoothPairContent(viewModel, tryAgainAction, openSettingAction, scanDeviceList)
            }
        }
```

That is my goal, but another problem raised that it gives error in `uiState` initialise time:

```kotlin
    var uiState by mutableStateOf<BluetoothConnectionUIState>(BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial)
            private set

**Error**

    Type mismatch.
    Required:
    BluetoothConnectionUIState
    Found:
    BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial
```

Again I am confused. Please guide me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I think you worked it out but just in case - you need `is` in your `when` to check if something `is` a class. When comparing to an `object` you use equality, which can just be written as the value to match)*

Working off your update:

```
// simplified for readability
sealed interface ConnectionUIState

sealed class BluetoothConnectionUIState {
    object Initial : ConnectionUIState
    data class ScanningDevice : BluetoothConnectionUIState()
}
```

You've got this object and class *nested inside* `BluetoothConnectionUIState`, which means their fully qualified names are things like `BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial`. But you don't actually have to nest them, you can do this:

```
sealed class BluetoothConnectionUIState
object Initial : ConnectionUIState
data class ScanningDevice : BluetoothConnectionUIState()
```

Now `Initial` and `ScanningDevice` aren't nested inside `BluetoothConnectionUIState`, you just reference them directly. So what's the relationship between them now? Look at the constructors:

```
// subclass of BluetoothConnectionUIState
data class ScanningDevice : BluetoothConnectionUIState()

// implements the ConnectionUIState interface
object Initial : ConnectionUIState
```

Once you remove the nesting, you can see that `Initial` actually has no type relationship with the sealed class at all! It just happened to be located inside it. And that's why you can't put it in your `mutableStateOf` - it's not a BluetoothConnectionUIState.

It's also why you were getting the *must be exhaustive* error in your original `when` block - you only had a branch checking `Initial`, which isn't part of the sealed class anyway. It works when you check `ScanningDevice`, because that's the only member of the class - if `uiState` is a `BluetoothConnectionUIState`, it must be a `ScanningDevice`.

---

How you fix this is up to you - seems like you want those two things to be part of the same sealed class. Maybe you want `ConnectionUIState` to be the sealed class? Since that's what they both represent. And have `BluetoothConnectionUIState` be the interface that you can apply selectively to certain members of that sealed class?

```
sealed interface BluetoothConnectionUIState

sealed class ConnectionUIState {
    object Initial : ConnectionUIState()
    data class ScanningDevice : ConnectionUIState(), BluetoothConnectionUIState
}
```

[This overview might be a helpful read too!](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/sealed-interfaces-kotlin/)

Comment: the above last example you give `interface BluetoothConnectionUIState` and `class ConnectionUIState` which one you assign type of `uiState` ? Thanks

Comment: actually I am using `mutableStatOf` and when I declare the variable I need to initialise it. So I thought  I can use `Initial` which is `object` type would be great. I am just heard there is new in `sealed interface` come in `1.5+` .  I thought `Initial` would be not implemented in `when` statement and which looks good. Is this possible through `sealed interface`.

Comment: Also `uiState` will provide `ScanningDevice` data class. Inside `when` statement I just need to check `is BluetoothConnectionUIState.ScanningDevice ` and I don't want error waning. Is this both case possible in this?

Comment: @vivekmodi in the example I gave at the end, `Initial` and `ScanningDevice` are both `ConnectionUIState`s because that's their superclass, they both call its constructor, same as usual. So if `uiState`'s type is `ConnectionUIState` then it could be either of those things, and your `when` block will require you to handle both of them as possibilities. I don't know what you're actually using the interface for, I just added it to `ScanningDevice` to show you can add it as a type, if you need to mark some `ConnectionUiState`s as being Bluetooth-specific (I'd probably use a subclass though)

Comment: Ok now I got it. Thank you so much for explaining me in detail.